# Uploading Multiple Files in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

How to input multiple files in typescript, not using react or angular, but using the interface and getter and setter in a class. For single file upload I have:

```
<input name="myfile" type="file" multiple/>
```

```
export interface IFile {
    file: string;
}
```

```
class FileElement {
get uploadFile(): string {
        return (this.querySelector('[name="myfile"]') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    }

set uploadFile(value: string) {
        (this.querySelector('[name="myfile"]') as HTMLInputElement).value = value;
    }

private fileHandler(evt: Event): void {
       const file: IFile = {
            uploadFile: this.uploadFile
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working for you here?

Comment: if I choose three files: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, only the first one - 1.jpg is transferred

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically set multiple files as input value using the [Data Transfer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) (check out [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#browser_compatibility), before using it).

The function below sets multiple [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) to an input.

```js
function setMultipleFiles(input: HTMLInputElement, data: File[]) {
  // ClipboardEvent.clipboardData has a greater support than the constructor
  // but the result it's the same
  const dt = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer(); 

  for (const file of data) {
    dt.items.add(file);
  }

  if (dt.files.length) {
    input.files = dt.files;
  }
}
```